# install intrernal and external packages

Tags: ros, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I would like to ask about some tutorials and helps installing some internal and external packages. I Installed them through some installation script. First I installed ROS Fuerte set the workspace. Than tried to install the two internal packages :  amcl_listener and pow_analyzer . I the error on the pow_analyzer package.

The error was

make: * No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.

With the amcl_listener make file was build and its not empty. But its not the case with the other internal package. So I think its about the dependence, so any help about that. Than also could not install the external package.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37593/install-intrernal-and-external-packages/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well thats also no magic. Just let ros install the package and let it fetch the dependency's by itself. The related tutorial is [here](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/rosinstall/html/rosws_tutorial.html).

```
i. cd ~/ros_workspace (I put all checked out packages in here)

ii. roslocate info package_name > package_name.rosinstall

iii. rosinstall . /etc/ros/diamondback|electric|fuerte package_name.rosinstall

iv. rosmake package_name (rosdep --install package_name to install system dependencies)

v. deal with ROS dependencies by iterating 1 or 2
```

---

Originally posted by [tlinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/2680/tlinder/) with karma: 663 on 2012-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1